# How one can adjust the rounded button background in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, button, colors, background

This is my rounded button's codes. It is in the drawable file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/teal_200"/>
    <corners android:radius="100dp"/>

</shape>
```

And that is my activiy_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRnd"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="272dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

There is no problem about shape btw it becomes rounded but  Normally my button color must be teal_200 which is turquoise but when it show up on the design it looks default color like ı did not assign any color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:backgroundTint="@null"`
`app:backgroundTint="@null"`
Add these lines to the xml code of the button.

Comment: God bless u dude. Have you encountered this situation before? How did you figure it out?

Comment: yeah i have encountered it many times, the issue is with the default tint values which override the background colours in android studio. I have reported this already to AS but looks like they have not yet seen fit to change it.